# All the command line command become "Not found" after installing Mountain lion

Tags: command-line, terminal, osx-mountain-lion, sudo

I just found after installing new Mountain lion, I can no longer use the command line because all the command seems to be " NOT Found", even for basic "sudo" command

sudo: command not found

How can i resolve my problem. I live together with command line.

Comment: Could it be the `PATH` is not being set? echo $PATH

Answer (score -1):

You should check your `$PATH` like suspectus says. 
You may need to `$ /bin/echo $PATH` or `/usr/bin/env`

Also try `$ /bin/bash --noprofile`, this will load you up without your startup files. If things are working then it's the startup files at fault.
Try `$ /bin/bash --verbose` to see what's being run when you start a bash shell, and then find the file this is in to fix it!
e.g `~/.bashrc, ~/.bash_profile, ~/.profile, /etc/profile, /etc/bash.bashrc`